# Why C++ map.insert() doesn't overwrite

Tags: c++

In the code below:

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  pair<int,int> p1(1,1);
  pair<int,int> p2(1,2);

  map<int,int> m;
  m.insert(p1);
  m.insert(p2);

  cout << "Map value: "<< m.at(1) << endl;

}
```

It printed out : `Map value: 1`, why `m.insert(p2)` doesn't overwrite the previous entity in the map?

Comment: That is expected behavior.

Comment: Because that's what the word "insert" means.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the [std::map::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) reference it is said that:

> Inserts element(s) into the container, if the container doesn't already contain an element with an equivalent key.

Answer (score 24):

[`map.insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) only inserts if the container doesn't already contain an element with an equivalent key.

You should use `operator[]` instead:

```
 m[p2.first] = p2.second;
```

Comment: As a nitpick: this operation requires that the mapped type be default-constructible and assignable.

Comment: too bad the line of code you have to write gets huge if the value doesnt have default constructor

Comment: What if I want to get iterator after insertion like in `insert()`?

Answer (score 6):

**Update as of C++17** There is now the [`std::map::insert_or_assign()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign) member function:

```
m.insert_or_assign(p1);
```

As the name suggests, if the key is already present then the value is assigned (and the key object kept) rather than erasing and freshly copy constructing the key and value. (So it's equivalent to the first of the two pre-C++17 snippets below.)

If you want an iterator pointing at the (new or updated) element, you again need to pick the value out of the returned pair. Since you're using C++17, you can now use a [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding):

```
auto [it, wasInserted] = m.insert_or_assign(p1);
```

---

**Before C++17** Putting together the other answers, if you want to avoid the assumption of being default constructable you get insert-with-overwrite code that looks like this:

```
auto itAndWasInserted = m.insert(p1);
if (!itAndWasInserted.second) {
    *(itAndWasInserted.first) = p1;
}
```

In the above snippet, if the element is already present then the new value is assigned to it. That's usually what you want. If you instead want to construct rather than assign the new value, but still want to avoid a second seek (after you've erased the original value), you end up with this monster:

```
auto itAndWasInserted = m.insert(p1);
auto it = itAndWasInserted.first;
if (!itAndWasInserted.second) {
    auto afterIt = m.erase(it);
    auto newItAndWasInserted = m.insert(afterIt, p1);  // Hint form of insert
    it = newItAndWasInserted.first;
}
```

At the end of the code block, `it` is an iterator pointing at the just-inserted element.

Realistically, in most cases you probably just want to use yizzlez's suggestion of `operator[]`, but I thought it would be good to note the theoretically best answer.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't overwrite. However if you check the return value, there is a `std::pair<iterator, bool>`. If bool is true, then it was inserted. If the bool is false, then it was not inserted because of a collision. At that point, you can then overwrite the data yourself by writing to the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to happen. `map.insert()` will only insert elements into the container if it doesn't already contain any elements, so this will ignore the later value elements assigned to it.